# Snapchat API PHP

Tags: php, snapchat

I am trying to figure out how SNAPI works (unofficial api for snapchat in php)

So here is the github link of the project.

```
https://github.com/mgp25/SC-API
```

Here it says.

```
Use registerTool.php https://github.com/mgp25/Snap-API/blob/master/examples/registerTool.php

Note: This is a CLI tool, not for webservers.

It will ask you for the account data:

Username: SnapTest

Password: thisIsMyPassword

Email: snaptest@myemail.com

Birthday (yyyy-mm-dd): 1970-01-01
```

With which CLI tool i can enter my own registration credentials though?

Because this php file has this code

```
<?php

include_once("../src/snapchat.php");


echo "\n\nUsername: ";
$username = trim(fgets(STDIN));

echo "\nPassword: ";
$password = trim(fgets(STDIN));

echo "\nEmail: ";
$email = trim(fgets(STDIN));

echo "\nBirthday (yyyy-mm-dd): ";
$birthday = trim(fgets(STDIN));

echo "\nGmail address: ";
$gMail = trim(fgets(STDIN));

echo "\nGmail password: ";
$gPasswd = trim(fgets(STDIN));

echo "\nCasper key: ";
$casperKey = trim(fgets(STDIN));

echo "\nCasper secret: ";
$casperSecret = trim(fgets(STDIN));

$snapchat = new Snapchat($username, $gMail, $gPasswd, $casperKey, $casperSecret, true);
```

I'm totally new to PHP and API's and im just trying to figure out how it works.
Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Does your code still work without the Casper client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Install XAMPP

2) find PHP.exe in your XAMPP folders ("C:\xampp\php\php.exe")

3) Copy PHP.exe path on the Environment Variables in Control Panel (if you are using windows), in the "PATH" section. If there is something else written there (for me it was "C:\Ruby200-x64\bin" you have to put a semicolumn ";" after it and then "C:\xampp\php" and it should look like this " C:\Ruby200-x64\bin; C:\xampp\php").
4) So now i assume you are in Windows, open Command Prompt CMD, and then navigate with the command "cd" to the folder that there is the registerTool.php file. Lets assume its on a folder on the desktop. put this on the CMD  "cd Desktop\SnapchatApi\examples\" and then enter.

5) Now its time to open the file. Type this command on CMD "php registerTool.php" and it will run the script via CMD.

I dont know if i helped you, for any question answer here.